# Why Ajax response in Wordpress doesn't work?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have odd (for me) problem with ajax in Wordpress. I do not receive proper response from server. I read Wordpress Codex to find out what I doing wrong, but still I have no clue.

I don't know if it is important or not, but when I tried add a type to ajax syntax, I received an error message.

```
class databaseClass
{
    function __construct()
    {

    if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) )  
       $protocol = 'https://';  
    else  
       $protocol = 'http://'; 

        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxScript', '/wp-content/themes/bulk/js/ajaxScript.js');
        wp_localize_script( 'ajaxScript', 'my_ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', $protocol ), 
                 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( '111')
            ) );
        add_action('wp_ajax_save_sort', 'ajaxFunctionInPHP');
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_sort', 'ajaxFunctionInPHP');  
    }

    function ajaxFunctionInPHP(){
        /*check_admin_referrer();
        $response['custom'] = "ssss";
        $response = json_encode($response);
        wp_send_json($response) ;*/

        ob_clean();
        $response['custom'] = "TEST";

        echo $response;
        die();  
    }
}

class ajaxClass extends databaseClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }





    public function ajaxPage()
    {
        echo '<form name="ajaxTest" type="POST">
             <input id="ajaxButton" type="button" value="KLIK"/>
             </form>
        ';
    }

}
```

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function () {
 jQuery('#ajaxButton').click(function() {
        var dataFromFunction="";
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',

            data: {
                action: 'save_sort',
                order: dataFromFunction
            },
            success: function (response){
                console.log("success message");
                console.log(response.custom)
            },
            error:  function (response){
                console.log("error message");
            }
        });
    });
} );
```

```
success message
ajaxScript.js?ver=5.0.4:15 undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct but I am sharing my personal approach to doing this in hopes that this might be helpful. Make changes to JS as mentioned below:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ($) {
    $('#ajaxButton').click(function() {
       var dataFromFunction="Test Data";
       $.ajax({
           url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
               action: 'save_sort',
               order: dataFromFunction
           },
       }).done( function (response){
           console.log("success message");
           console.log(response.custom)
       }).fail(function (response){
           console.log("error message");
       }).always(function(){
           console.log('Ajax Completed');
       });
    });
});
```

Also for your script localization, it is good to define the scheme parameter in `admin_url` function but not necessary so `'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')` should be just fine.

You seem to have created nonce but haven't used it and a good practice would be to use create nonce function in your form section and not in localization.

I do have a suggestion for your ajax response function but this is just an advice. Change your function to return as follows:

```
function ajaxFunctionInPHP(){
    $response['dataFromFunction'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['dataFromFunction']);
    wp_send_json( $response);
}
```

Good Luck!!